# Cross-Origin Request (CORS) in ( Yii2 Framework + Ionic )

Tags: php, ionic-framework, yii2, cors, http-headers

I'm trying to make some HTTP requests from my Ionic project to my Yii2 backend. But when I try to get data I'm getting the cross-origin issue, I don't know what to change in my Yii2 settings.

I've already tried to make a proxy for my request, and also make Cordova request but none of them worked, I think it's all about Yii2 settings.

Here is my filters/cors.php file in Yii2

```
class Cors extends ActionFilter
{
    /**
     * @var Request the current request. If not set, the `request` application component will be used.
     */
    public $request;
    /**
     * @var Response the response to be sent. If not set, the `response` application component will be used.
     */
    public $response;
    /**
     * @var array define specific CORS rules for specific actions
     */
    public $actions = [];
    /**
     * @var array Basic headers handled for the CORS requests.
     */
    public $cors = [
        'Origin' => ['*'],
        'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
        'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400
    ];


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->request = $this->request ?: Yii::$app->getRequest();
        $this->response = $this->response ?: Yii::$app->getResponse();

        $this->overrideDefaultSettings($action);

        $requestCorsHeaders = $this->extractHeaders();
        $responseCorsHeaders = $this->prepareHeaders($requestCorsHeaders);
        $this->addCorsHeaders($this->response, $responseCorsHeaders);

        if ($this->request->isOptions && $this->request->headers->has('Access-Control-Request-Method')) {
            // it is CORS preflight request, respond with 200 OK without further processing
            $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Override settings for specific action.
     * @param \yii\base\Action $action the action settings to override
     */
    public function overrideDefaultSettings($action)
    {
        if (isset($this->actions[$action->id])) {
            $actionParams = $this->actions[$action->id];
            $actionParamsKeys = array_keys($actionParams);
            foreach ($this->cors as $headerField => $headerValue) {
                if (in_array($headerField, $actionParamsKeys)) {
                    $this->cors[$headerField] = $actionParams[$headerField];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Extract CORS headers from the request.
     * @return array CORS headers to handle
     */
    public function extractHeaders()
    {
        $headers = [];
        foreach (array_keys($this->cors) as $headerField) {
            $serverField = $this->headerizeToPhp($headerField);
            $headerData = isset($_SERVER[$serverField]) ? $_SERVER[$serverField] : null;
            if ($headerData !== null) {
                $headers[$headerField] = $headerData;
            }
        }

        return $headers;
    }

    /**
     * For each CORS headers create the specific response.
     * @param array $requestHeaders CORS headers we have detected
     * @return array CORS headers ready to be sent
     */
    public function prepareHeaders($requestHeaders)
    {
        $responseHeaders = [];
        // handle Origin
        if (isset($requestHeaders['Origin'], $this->cors['Origin'])) {
            if (in_array($requestHeaders['Origin'], $this->cors['Origin'], true)) {
                $responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = $requestHeaders['Origin'];
            }

            if (in_array('*', $this->cors['Origin'], true)) {
                // Per CORS standard (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org), wildcard origins shouldn't be used together with credentials
                if (isset($this->cors['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials']) && $this->cors['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials']) {
                    if (YII_DEBUG) {
                        throw new InvalidConfigException("Allowing credentials for wildcard origins is insecure. Please specify more restrictive origins or set 'credentials' to false in your CORS configuration.");
                    } else {
                        Yii::error("Allowing credentials for wildcard origins is insecure. Please specify more restrictive origins or set 'credentials' to false in your CORS configuration.", __METHOD__);
                    }
                } else {
                    $responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
                }
            }
        }

        $this->prepareAllowHeaders('Headers', $requestHeaders, $responseHeaders);

        if (isset($requestHeaders['Access-Control-Request-Method'])) {
            $responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = implode(', ', $this->cors['Access-Control-Request-Method']);
        }

        if (isset($this->cors['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'])) {
            $responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = $this->cors['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] ? 'true' : 'false';
        }

        if (isset($this->cors['Access-Control-Max-Age']) && $this->request->getIsOptions()) {
            $responseHeaders['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = $this->cors['Access-Control-Max-Age'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->cors['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'])) {
            $responseHeaders['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = implode(', ', $this->cors['Access-Control-Expose-Headers']);
        }
        
        if (isset($this->cors['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'])) {
            $responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = implode(', ', $this->cors['Access-Control-Allow-Headers']);
        }

        return $responseHeaders;
    }

    /**
     * Handle classic CORS request to avoid duplicate code.
     * @param string $type the kind of headers we would handle
     * @param array $requestHeaders CORS headers request by client
     * @param array $responseHeaders CORS response headers sent to the client
     */
    protected function prepareAllowHeaders($type, $requestHeaders, &$responseHeaders)
    {
        $requestHeaderField = 'Access-Control-Request-' . $type;
        $responseHeaderField = 'Access-Control-Allow-' . $type;
        if (!isset($requestHeaders[$requestHeaderField], $this->cors[$requestHeaderField])) {
            return;
        }
        if (in_array('*', $this->cors[$requestHeaderField])) {
            $responseHeaders[$responseHeaderField] = $this->headerize($requestHeaders[$requestHeaderField]);
        } else {
            $requestedData = preg_split('/[\\s,]+/', $requestHeaders[$requestHeaderField], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            $acceptedData = array_uintersect($requestedData, $this->cors[$requestHeaderField], 'strcasecmp');
            if (!empty($acceptedData)) {
                $responseHeaders[$responseHeaderField] = implode(', ', $acceptedData);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds the CORS headers to the response.
     * @param Response $response
     * @param array $headers CORS headers which have been computed
     */
    public function addCorsHeaders($response, $headers)
    {
        if (empty($headers) === false) {
            $responseHeaders = $response->getHeaders();
            foreach ($headers as $field => $value) {
                $responseHeaders->set($field, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert any string (including php headers with HTTP prefix) to header format.
     *
     * Example:
     *  - X-PINGOTHER -> X-Pingother
     *  - X_PINGOTHER -> X-Pingother
     * @param string $string string to convert
     * @return string the result in "header" format
     */
    protected function headerize($string)
    {
        $headers = preg_split('/[\\s,]+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $headers = array_map(function ($element) {
            return str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace(['_', '-'], [' ', ' '], $element))));
        }, $headers);
        return implode(', ', $headers);
    }

    /**
     * Convert any string (including php headers with HTTP prefix) to header format.
     *
     * Example:
     *  - X-Pingother -> HTTP_X_PINGOTHER
     *  - X PINGOTHER -> HTTP_X_PINGOTHER
     * @param string $string string to convert
     * @return string the result in "php $_SERVER header" format
     */
    protected function headerizeToPhp($string)
    {
        return 'HTTP_' . strtoupper(str_replace([' ', '-'], ['_', '_'], $string));
    }
}
```

I expect to get the same JSON data in my Ionic app that I get when I enter the URL in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `yii\filters\Cors`

`Yii` offers a class that you can use directly. You can add it as a `behavior` directly in your controllers customizing the `behaviors()` method.

```
use yii\filters\Cors;
use yii\rest\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller // or ActiveController
{
    // Customize the verbs as needed
    private $_verbs = ['GET','POST','PATCH','PUT','DELETE'];

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        // remove auth filter
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => Cors::class,
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => $this->_verbs,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['content-type'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            ],
        ];

        // re-add authentication filter
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::class,
        ];

        // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

        return $behaviors;
    }

    // Some other methods here if needed

    /**
     * Send the HTTP options available to this route
     */
    public function actionOptions()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS') {
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(405);
        }

        Yii::$app->getResponse()->getHeaders()->set('Allow', implode(', ', $this->_verbs));
    }
}
```

Notice that, if you are using the authentication filter, it needs to be disabled before adding the cors filter, then reset. From the documentation:

> Adding the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing filter to a controller is a bit more complicated than adding other filters described above, because the CORS filter has to be applied before authentication methods and thus needs a slightly different approach compared to other filters. Also authentication has to be disabled for the CORS Preflight requests so that a browser can safely determine whether a request can be made beforehand without the need for sending authentication credentials.

There is more info on the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers#cors).

Answer (score 0):

For other users. You may have an error in your code. Double-click on the OPTIONS request will open a new tab, and Yii will send you an error message.

[image: OPTIONS request]